# How can I search for rows that contain a non-alphanumeric or space character?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, non-alphanumeric

I want to search a table for all rows that contain a non-alphanumeric *and* non-space character in a specific field. What I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myField LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

As far as I can tell, this returns all non-alphanumeric fields. However, spaces are fine, so I don't want to return rows where the only non-alphanumeric character is a space. How can I adjust this query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about you add the space:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myField LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%'
```

Comment: Now I'm confused (and feel silly). I thought I just tried that and it didn't work... But I just tried again and it did :-/ Maybe it's just too early in the morning... thanks!

Comment: It doesn't let me accept the answer yet... I will in about 8 minutes :)